# Symfony 2.8 Easyadmin DataTransformer for enum(yes, no) fields to represent boolean in forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I use easyadmin to generate backend needs.I really loved to control boolean values with nice switch off / on ui feature in the list view.

But I don't use boolean values as `tinyint(1) 1 or 0`, I use as `ENUM('yes', 'no')`. So in symfony forms I use `DataTransformer` to convert `yes to 1` when sending to view, and `1 to yes` when sending to model. But I couldn't find any related documentation how could I use data transformer or event listener in easyadmin. I see several dispatches and events are exists in easyadmin.

[Events](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Event/EasyAdminEvents.php)

Do you have any idea how could I add dataTransformer preferably, or event listener.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find an another solution which solves the problem without any need of DataTransformers or Listeners. In [Doc](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/getting-started/4-views-and-actions.md#virtual-properties) it mentions about virtual Entity methods. So I put following methods which haven't related with any entity properties directly.

```
public function setBoolHost($isHost)
{
    return $this->setHost($isHost ? EntityInterface::YES : EntityInterface::NO);
}

public function getBoolHost()
{
    return ($this->getHost() == EntityInterface::YES) ? true : false;
}
```

So in `config.yml easy_admin:` config looks as following

```
entities:
    Members:
        list:
            fields:
                - { property: 'boolHost', type: 'toggle', label : 'Is Host ?'}
```

I hope it is help to someone who needs a solution to kind of this problem.